# Cannot see files on a backed up disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ntfs, file-permissions

I made a full copy of the files from one disk to a backup disk before formatting my pc. I connected the disk to my laptop and now I cannot see the contents even though i can see the disk is 75% full.

I think I may have added the switch to robocopy to copy files with permissions. How can I revert this?

I made Everyone the owner of the files and windows ran through all the files so I know they are definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the owner isn't enough. You need to modify the permissions.Change the owner to .\Administrator is the ideal practice.

Comment: I have tried this using the everyone group, but I will give it a try with Administrator and get back although I am pretty sure it wont make a difference.